# Give my URLs bodies using the URLComponents approach in Swift

Tags: swift, url

I'm building my API architecture and want to start programmatically composing my URLs. However, I am not clear on how to give my URLs bodies using the URLComponents approach in Swift. Is it with the `components.query` method?

Code so far:

```
func getURL(scheme: String, host: String, port: Int, path: String) -> URL {
    var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = scheme
    components.host = host
    components.port = port
    components.path = path
    return components.url!
}
```

Comment: What are bodies in this context? Maybe you could add an example of what you want to do.

Comment: My use case is passing parameters for my Node.js server to query my neo4j AuraDB

Comment: I assumed this happened it the URL itself, but as Rob points out, that might not be the case.

Comment: Actually, I'm guessing that for at least my get requests, I can just use the `components.queryItems` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An URL does not include a body. Both headers and bodies are distinct from an URL. If your web service supports receiving parameters in the query, then that may work for you, but it it's distinct from the body. URLComponents is just a useful tool for building and parsing an URL.

If you want to combine an URL, headers, body, and some policies, see [URLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest).

Comment: So I would pass the composed URL to the `URLRequest` init, then specify a body using the `.httpBody` method?

Comment: Correct, if you have the entire body available as a Data. Or use the httpBodyStream to provide the body as an InputStream over time (for example, to send a large file).